# Swift - Memory increasing when going 'in' and 'back' from UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, memory, uiviewcontroller

I am going in and out of `UIViewController`s.
Every time I am going in memory increases, but when I am getting out (pressing Back) memory **is not** decreasing.

I have weak `@IBOutlet`s, vars and lets.

How can I fix it?

p.s. One of the `@IBOutlet` is container pointing to another `UIViewController`

Comment: Have you tried using instruments to see what is being retained?

Comment: Try setting breakpoint to deinit(Swift) or dealloc(Obj-c) method, and see if it is called. And provide some code

Comment: If you are using Master-Detail Application template with iOS 8+, be aware that when you hit back, view is still there until you push another view. You can easily see this behavior if you write some debug code at deinit or dealloc code as @katleta3000 mentioned.

Comment: @katleta3000, deinit is not called! I guess I have a retain cycle

Answer (score 2):

Ignore the comments suggesting retain/release breakpoints and peppering your code with log calls; that's an unwieldy tactic that misses entire classes of problems. Abizern's suggestion to use Instruments is a lot more spot-on. Run the Leaks instrument to look for leaked instances. Browse the other memory instruments as well. Instruments is a &@&$&-ing magical debugging tool and so many developers ignore it for reasons I can't fathom. Spend a few minutes with a tutorial and you'll save months of debugging time over your career.

Comment: I'll try it. Thank you. And please let me know what you think about what I've already found: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33275276/1341180

Comment: Difficult to say but it does look like your approach is making for some awkward juggling. You'll need to update your question with a more detailed description of your architecture and how you're passing data between them. Something seems ... odd. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are creating a new UIViewController every time you switch between views.  Try to create the segue to be an unwind segue, this will remove the current view from the stack.  Otherwise it appears that you are just continually adding to the stack of views.  Tell me if this works.

Comment: I am using segues, I just forgot to release the item I was transferring to child VC before dismissing the VC.